# Display Pandas Dataframe in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyinstaller, pandas-styles

I have a question about displaying a data frame in an executable python file. I read a table from an excel file as a data frame and display it in the console as given below:

```
game_log_np = ReadGameLog()
num_game_log = game_log_np.shape[0]
game_log_df = pd.DataFrame(game_log_np, columns = ["Date","Time","Difficulty","Number Range","Guess Limit","Result"])
if condition:
    display(DisplayDataFrame(game_log_df, num_game_log))
```

When the condition is true, the `game_log_df` data frame is displayed with the custom style defined in `DisplayDataFrame` function, as given:

```
def DisplayDataFrame(df, num_game_log):
    return df.style.applymap(DifficultyBackgroundColor, subset="Difficulty")\
                   .applymap(ResultBackgroundColor, subset="Result")\
                   .applymap(EvenBackgroundColor,
                             subset=(slice(0, num_game_log, 2), ["Date","Time","Number Range","Guess Limit"]))\
                   .applymap(OddBackgroundColor,
                             subset=(slice(1, num_game_log, 2), ["Date","Time","Number Range","Guess Limit"]))\
                   .applymap_index(TitleBackgroundColor)\
                   .applymap_index(TitleBackgroundColor, axis="columns")
```

When I run the code in the jupyter notebook, everything is fine and the data frame is displayed at the console window as I expect. However, when I convert the .ipynb file to a .py file and create an executable file with PyInstaller, the only output is `<pandas.io.formats.style.styler object at ...>` and the data frame is not displayed at all. Is there any solution to show the customized data frame in the exe application?

I have uploaded the full script on my [GitHub](https://github.com/burakozpoyraz/Guess-Number/blob/main/GuessNumber.ipynb). I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: The short answer is no; not with the built-in styler. You need an environment (like Jupyter) which is capable of rendering HTML to display the styler without exporting to a file. There may be terminals that can do this natively (or add-ons that can add this functionality), but in general if you're looking for a graphical application something like [pandastable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html) / [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) or other graphical application tool would be better.

Comment: Dear @HenryEcker, thank you for your explanation. I guess I have to use a graphical application tool as you mentioned.